# Hole punching — where to put external IPs?

Tags: c#, p2p, hole-punching

I'm trying to implement [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))  using C# but unfortunately I spent hours to figure out why it doesn't work for me.  Here is my problem:

I have a third part server that I can manage all external IPs for the peers on, and of course my router is behind a NAT, and I assume all my peers are also behind NATs.

Say if I managed to figure out all slaves (peers), End points (external ips). Where to put the external ip address of my server which runs on my pc (not the third party one), and where to put the peer ip address?

This is my code:

```
public void HolePunch(String ServerIp, Int32 Port) // if I put my external ip here I get Exception (An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used)
{
    IPEndPoint LocalPt = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0], Port);
    UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
    Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    Client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    Client.Client.Bind(LocalPt);

    IPEndPoint RemotePt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIp), Port);

    // This Part Sends your local endpoint to the server so if the two peers are on the same nat they can bypass it, you can omit this if you wish to just use the remote endpoint.
    byte[] IPBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].ToString());
    byte[] LengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPBuffer.Length);
    byte[] PortBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(Port);
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[IPBuffer.Length + LengthBuffer.Length + PortBuffer.Length];
    LengthBuffer.CopyTo(Buffer,0);
    IPBuffer.CopyTo(Buffer, LengthBuffer.Length);
    PortBuffer.CopyTo(Buffer, IPBuffer.Length + LengthBuffer.Length);
    Client.BeginSend(Buffer, Buffer.Length, RemotePt, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), Client);

    // Wait to receve something
    BeginReceive(Client, Port);

    // you may want to use a auto or manual ResetEvent here and have the server send back a confirmation, the server should have now stored your local (you sent it) and remote endpoint.

    // you now need to work out who you need to connect to then ask the server for there remote and local end point then need to try to connect to the local first then the remote.
    // if the server knows who you need to connect to you could just have it send you the endpoints as the confirmation.

    // you may also need to keep this open with a keepalive packet untill it is time to connect to the peer or peers.

    // once you have the endpoints of the peer you can close this connection unless you need to keep asking the server for other endpoints

    Client.Close();
}

public void ConnectToPeer(String PeerIp, Int32 Port)
{
    IPEndPoint LocalPt = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0], Port);
    UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
    Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    Client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    Client.Client.Bind(LocalPt);
    IPEndPoint RemotePt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(PeerIp), Port);
    Client.Connect(RemotePt);
    //you may want to keep the peer client connections in a list.

    BeginReceive(Client, Port);
}

public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    UdpClient Client = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
    Client.EndSend(ar);
}

public void BeginReceive(UdpClient Client, Int32 Port)
{
    IPEndPoint ListenPt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);

    Object[] State = new Object[] { Client, ListenPt };

    Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), State);
}

public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    UdpClient Client = (UdpClient)((Object[])ar.AsyncState)[0];
    IPEndPoint ListenPt = (IPEndPoint)((Object[])ar.AsyncState)[0];

    Byte[] receiveBytes = Client.EndReceive(ar, ref ListenPt);
}
```

EDIT :
the code works will if I give it my local ip and if my clients in my pc .. but if I supply it an external ip it doesn't work ( the exception in the first line comment )

Comment: What is your port number and is it being blocked on the remote machine? Also, it would be very helpful if you posted the values for ServerIp and Port.

Comment: I chosen 20000 as a port number , and no it not blocked
my server IP is : 188.247.78.18 ( external from www.whatismyip.com) port : 20000